# Como colocar uma imagem em um link no rodapé?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, gostaria de vincular uma imagem do ícone do linkedIn com o link do meu perfil, para colocar no rodapé e alinhá-lo ao centro do rodapé. Como ficaria o código?

```css
footer#rodape {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(Background-baixo.jpg);
    padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<footer id='rodape'>
        <img class="rodape-baixo" src="rodape.png">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 - by Bruno Menaguali</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bruno-menaguali/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></p>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só colocar a imagem como conteúdo da tag *`<a href="" > <img/></a>`*

```
<footer id='rodape'>
<a href="https://linkedin.com/seu-perfil"><img class="rodape-baixo" src="rodape.png"></a>        

<p>Copyright &copy; 2020 - by Bruno Menaguali</p>

<p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bruno-menaguali/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></p>

</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara, você tem que usar Font Awesome 
recomendo [fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com](http://fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com)
só buscar o ícone que deseja no site e colocar

Adiciona no seu código:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Meu, pra que que o cara vai importar um CSS de não sei quantos KBs, com mais de 300 ícones, para usar apenas a imagem do Linkedin...